# Safari Mobile: pointer-events CSS does not work for SVG content

Tags: css, ipad, safari, svg

I am having trouble getting pointer-events CSS to work properly when applied to an SVG element.  It does not behave as expected when using the iPad.

I've created a small demo of the problem here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nPFu2/

If anyone has run into this before or has any insight to this, I am super appreciative for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Safari still appears to have this problem with svg pointer events.

They work fine in Webkit and Chrome, so I guess it's just a Safari bug that they haven't yet fixed.

... After some more research, I figured out the confusion. Safari does currently support pointer events on svg elements, but this does not include the svg tag itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i solved it like this.

1. Place the svg inside an `<a>` tag
2. Define a ":after" element for the `<a>`

```css
 a::after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  top:0;
} 
svg {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:alert('click');">Click me
<svg id="svgpath" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; cursor: crosshair !important; pointer-events: none; " height="100" version="1.1" width="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.3; " fill="none" stroke="#ffff00" d="M9 12L85 11" stroke-width="15" opacity="0.3"></path></svg>
</a>
```

It should work.

[Updated fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/nPFu2/34/)