# How to disable click through on element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've implemented *click event* on `.parent_2`, but when I click on it, it does not work on **iPAD**.

Please help.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="parent_1">
   <div class="parent_2">
      <svg></svg>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.parent_1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 16px;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: 3;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 320px;
   border-radius: 0 0 0 3px;
   -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
   transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.parent_2 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 7px;
   right: 7px;
   z-index: 3;
   display: block;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: #fff;
}

svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.15s ease-in-out;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay: Good job. I was struggling to format the code. :-)

Comment: It works everywhere except iPad

Comment: Js is not important because it works on PC's and android tablets. I think here is a css problem.

Comment: I know that `pointer-events:none` didn't used to work in old Safari (5.1). Not sure about whether that applies to newer versions of Safari....it is Safari, right?

Comment: It is Safari, but the last one

Comment: Then perhaps they haven't fixed it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522518/safari-mobile-pointer-events-css-does-not-work-for-svg-content

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: I tried to replace svg by <div> with the same css properties and it did not work too.